# Python Record Linkage, Fuzzy Match and Deduplication

Tags: python, duplicates, fuzzywuzzy, record-linkage, python-dedupe

I have 3 dataset of customers with 7 columns.

> CustomerName
>
> Address
>
> Phone
>
> StoreName
>
> Mobile
>
> Longitude
>
> Latitude

every dataset has 13000-18000 record. I am trying to fuzzy match for deduplication between them. my data set columns don't have same weight in this matching. How i can handle it????
Do you know good library for my case?

Comment: @fgregg can i use dedupe for this case?

Comment: Yes Dedupe will work here, just merge 3 datasets into one and run thru the dedupe to get the required clusters for the probable duplicates, I've used dedupe extensively for such kind of task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Recordlinkage library would suit your purposes

you can use to the Compare object , requiring various kinds of matches:

```
compare_cl.exact('CustomerName', 'CustomerName', label='CustomerName')
compare_cl.string('StoreName', 'StoreName', method='jarowinkler', threshold=0.85, label='surname')
compare_cl.string('Address', 'Address', threshold=0.85, label='Address')
```

then defining the match you can customize how you want results, ie if you want 2 features to be matched at least

```
features = compare_cl.compute(pairs, df)    
matches = features[features.sum(axis=1) > 3]
```